# Añadir elementos dinámicamente en Select2 que se reciben a través de un controlador de Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7, select2

Tengo un controlador con laravel donde envío un array hacia una vista en blade.

En esta vista blade tengo un select2 y quiero añadir dinámicamente estos valores.

Tengo este código donde recibo 4 valores pero solo me añade el último

El problema creo que está en el "bucle" ya que si pongo este código sí que me añade 2 ítems (pero sin iguales) al select2, por lo que el problema lo tengo en el bucle.

El problema creo que lo tengo aquí, tal como trato el objeto *ingredientes*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
@extends('layouts.user-guest')

@section('content')
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Laravel - Dynamic autocomplete search using select2 JS Ajax-nicesnippets.com</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

```
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h3>Mostrando recetas con los ingredientes</h3>
                    <form>
                        <select class="itemName form-control" name="itemName" id="itemName" multiple="multiple"></select>
                        <button type="button" id="buscarReceta" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar recetas</button>
                    </form>

                    <div id="contenedorListadoRecetas" style="display: none; padding-top: 10px">
                        <div id="listadoRecetas" style="display: none">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
</div>

</html>
@endsection



@section('script')

<script type="text/javascript">


    $('.itemName').select2({
        placeholder: 'Selecciona uno o más ingredientes',
        ajax: {
            url: '/tags/find',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            text: item.descripcion,
                            id: item.real_id
                        }
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });


    ingredientes = {!! json_encode($ingredientes) !!};
    
    $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(ingredientes))).each(function() {

        console.log(this.real_id);
        console.log(this.descripcion);

        $(".itemName").append('<option value=' + this.real_id+ '>' + this.descripcion + '</option>').val(this.real_id);
        $(".itemName").val(this.real_id);


    });


</script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Sencillo, un ejemplo de esto puede ser:
HTML

```
 <select name="seller_id" id="seller_id " class="form-control itemName select2"></select>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
   

      let html="";
      $(".itemName").html("")
      let data={!! json_encode($ingredientes) !!};
      html=`<option value="">Seleccione</option>`
      data.filter(i=>{
          html+=`<option value="${i.real_id}">${i.description}</option>` 
   
      })
      $(".itemName").append(html)
    </script>
```

Con esto, agregas normalmente en el select con la clase select2. Si ha fallado, contactame por twitter @puntozap o por este medio.

Saludos

Comment: No me da error en la consola, pero tampoco me añade los elementos.

Comment: podrias mostrar que error sale?

Comment: Digo, que no me da error en la consola (no sale error)

Comment: Necesito mas contexto, ver como lo estas haciendo en el codigo. desde el html hasta el javascript

Comment: ok gracias @puntuzap edito el primer mensaje con más info